# Python - splitting lines in txt file by semicolon in order to extract a text title...except sometimes the title has semicolons in it

Tags: python, csv, rename, file-rename

So, I have an extremely inefficient way to do this that works, which I'll show, as it will help illustrate the problem more clearly.  I'm an absolute beginner in python and this is definitely not "the python way" nor "remotely sane."

I have a .txt file where each line contains information about a large number of .csv files, following format:

File; Title; Units; Frequency; Seasonal Adjustment; Last Updated

(first entry:)
0\00XALCATM086NEST.csv;Harmonized Index of Consumer Prices: Overall Index Excluding Alcohol and Tobacco for AustriaÂ©; Index 2005=100; M; NSA; 2015-08-24

and so on, repeats like this for a while.  For anyone interested, this is the St.Louis Fed (FRED) data.

I want to rename each file (currently named the alphanumeric code @ the start, 00XA etc), to the text name.  So, just split by semicolon, right?  Except, sometimes, the text title has semicolons within it (and I want all of the text).

So I did:

```
data_file_data_directory = 'C:\*****\Downloads\FRED2_csv_3\FRED2_csv_2'
rename_data_file_name = 'README_SERIES_ID_SORT.txt'
rename_data_file = open(data_file_data_directory + '\\' + rename_data_file_name)
for line in rename_data_file.readlines():
    data = line.split(';')
    if len(data) > 2 and data[0].rstrip().lstrip() != 'File':
        original_file_name = data[0]
```

These last 2 lines deal with the fact that there is some introductory text that we want to skip, and we don't want to rename based on the legend @ the top (!= 'File').  It saves the 00XAL__.csv as the oldname.  It may be possible to make this more elegant (I would appreciate the tips), but it's the next part (the new, text name) that gets really ugly.

```
if len(data) ==6:
            new_file_name = data[0][:-4].split("\\")[-1] + '-' + data[1][:-2].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ')
        else:
            if len(data) ==7:
                new_file_name = data[0][:-4].split("\\")[-1] + '-' + data[1].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[2][:-2].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ')
            else:
                if len(data) ==8:
                    new_file_name = data[0][:-4].split("\\")[-1] + '-' + data[1].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[2].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[3][:-2].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ')
                else:
                    if len(data) ==9:
                        new_file_name = data[0][:-4].split("\\")[-1] + '-' + data[1].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[2].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[3].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[4][:-2].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ')
                    else:
                        if len(data) ==10:
                            new_file_name = data[0][:-4].split("\\")[-1] + '-' + data[1].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[2].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[3].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[4].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ') + '-' + data[5][:-2].replace(':',' -').replace('"','').replace('/',' or ')
                        else:
```

(etc)

What I'm doing here is that there is no way to know for each line in the .csv how many items are in the list created by splitting it by semicolons.  Ideally, the list would be length 6 - as follows the key @ the top of my example of the data.  However, for every semicolon in the text name, the length increases by 1...and we want everything before the last four items in the list (counting backwards from the right: date, seasonal adjustment, frequency, units/index) but after the .csv code (this is just another way of saying, I want the text "title" - everything for each line after .csv but before units/index).

Really what I want is just a way to save the entirety of the text name as "new_name" for each line, even after I split each line by semicolon, when I have no idea how many semicolons are in each text name or the line as a whole.  The above code achieves this, but OMG, this can't be the right way to do this.

Please let me know if it's unclear or if I can provide more info.

Comment: Instead of parsing it yourself with `split()`, use the `csv` module. If the input file was automatically generated by some other CSV program, it should work. They have ways to handle cells that contain the delimiter.

Comment: im not sure if it was generated that way - but it has to have been automatically generated somehow (280k lines).  I'll look into that module.  I feel like a for loop would address what I'm doing but I'm not sure how to conceptualize things.